# Previewing SQL Server Reports in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

Is there any way to preview reports in Visual Studio without having to put them in a `ReportViewer` control, and stopping and relaunching the app anytime I want to make a change to the report? I am creating the reports in Visual Studio to be used by an app I'm building in Lightswitch.

I tried setting up SQL Server Reporting Services, but I encountered permission issues attempting to use the reporting server on my localhost and it seems that a deployment step would still be required to view my reports there anyway. My goal is to make changes to the reports and be able to preview them without a build step. It doesn't take the Lightswitch solution that long to build, I'm just looking to make development more efficient if possible.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that is possible. It is possible through BIDS though...

> The Visual Studio Report Designer is similar to the user interface in
>   Business Intelligence Development Studio in SQL Server 2008 R2 or
>   later, **except that it does not have the preview functionality** and it
>   saves the reports in .rdlc files rather than .rdl files. For more
>   information about Report Designer in Business Intelligence Development
>   Studio, see Reporting Services Reports in SQL Server Books Online.

[Report Designer (Visual Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb558708.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I have the full version of Visual Studio on my localhost, but the full version of SQL Server is only running on the production server, so I don't have BIDS on my localhost...is there an express version of BIDS? Although it might be a moot point if there's no easy way to use the reports created in BIDS in my Lightswitch project...